# How Do I use the formats in DateTime::Locale with a DateTime object?

Tags: perl, datetime, locale

[DateTime::Locale](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aLocale) has a very comprehensive list of date and time formats for various locales and countries. I would like to use it in emails to customers, depending on which country the customer is from.

Unfortunately, it is a little hard to understand from the documentation how to actually use the functions for a medium or a long date. For example, [DateTime::Locale::de_DE](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aLocale%3a%3ade_DE) lists these [date formats](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aLocale%3a%3ade_DE#Date-Formats) (excerpt) in the doc:

> ```
> Long
>  2008-02-05T18:30:30 = 5. Februar 2008
>  1995-12-22T09:05:02 = 22. Dezember 1995
> -0010-09-15T04:44:23 = 15. September -10
>
> Medium
>  2008-02-05T18:30:30 = 05.02.2008
>  1995-12-22T09:05:02 = 22.12.1995
>  -0010-09-15T04:44:23 = 15.09.-010
> ```

This is great. According to [DateTime::Locale::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aLocale%3a%3aBase) there are methods in the locale object to get these formats: `$locale->date_format_long()` and `$locale->date_format_medium()`.

After some googling I came up with [Sinan Ünür's blog](http://blog.nu42.com/2011/12/how-can-i-print-dates-in-multiple.html), where he shows this code (excerpt):

> ```
> for my $locale ( qw(ar da de en_GB es fr ru tr) ) {
>     $dt->set_locale( $locale );
>     print_date( $dt );
> }
>
> sub print_date {
>     my ($dt) = @_;
>     my $locale = $dt->locale;
>
>     printf(
>         "In %s: %s\n", $locale->name,
>         $dt->format_cldr($locale->date_format_full)
>     );
> }
> ```

So the format that comes out of these methods is a cldr format. Cool. But what Sinan shows looks tedius. In short, it would be:

```
for (qw( ar da de en_GB es fr ru tr )) {
  my $dt2 = DateTime->now( locale => $_ );
  printf "%s: %s\n", $_, $dt2->format_cldr($dt2->locale->date_format_long);
}
```

In order to make that shorter, I could of course do something like this:

```
package DateTime;

sub stringify_long {
  return $_[0]->format_cldr($_[0]->locale->date_format_long);
}

package Main;
use strict; use warnings;    
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now( locale => 'de_DE' );
print $dt->stringify_long;
```

But I don't want to do that. So my question: **Is there a way to stringify a DateTime object according to one of these formats from its locale with a build-in method that I am missing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your opposition is to Sinan Ünür's method, so I don't know if this will appeal to you or not, but you can specify a formatter object to control stringification of `DateTime` objects:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::CLDR;
use DateTime::Locale;

my $locale = DateTime::Locale->load('de_DE');
my $formatter = DateTime::Format::CLDR->new(
    pattern => $locale->date_format_long,
    locale => $locale
);
my $dt = DateTime->now( locale => $locale, formatter => $formatter );
print $dt;
```

or

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::CLDR;
use DateTime::Locale;

my $locale = DateTime::Locale->load('de_DE');
my $dt = DateTime->now( locale => $locale );
my $formatter = DateTime::Format::CLDR->new(
    pattern => $locale->date_format_long,
    locale => $locale
);
$dt->set_formatter($formatter);
print $dt;
```

The nice thing about this approach is that once you've set a formatter, printing the date is easy-peasy.

Comment: A formatter seems to be a good option. Thanks for demonstrating it. I am primarily looking for an option that is less repetition if I do that kind of thing a lot.